# Split/Explode in String identifying only the first element (Symbol or Word)?

Tags: php, string, split, explode

I have the the next string:

```
String = "Name: James, Training, Physician, Hobbies: Sports, Reading, Age: 24".
```

With the following string to share with just the first ':' found, making the following:

```
stringsplit1 = "Name";
stringsplit2 = "James, Training, Physician, Hobbies: Sports, Reading, Age: 24";
```

or in the array. : S

Comment: where is your `explode()` ?

Comment: you should be able to do this with the 3rd argument of `explode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
explode(':',$string,2);
                    ^ ------------> limit [int]
```

Complete code:

```
$string = "Name: James, Training, Physician, Hobbies: Sports, Reading, Age: 24";
$ar = explode(":",$string,2);
print_r($ar);
```